# How to find and import missing image files that primefaces accordion uses into maven project?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, icons, accordion

Recently I inherited a jsf web application built upon jsf 2.0 and Primefaces 5.3. I noticed that primefaces accordion panel that contains multiple primefaces tab does not display icon (e.g. ui-icon-triangle-1-s). When I inspected a xhtml page where the accordion panel is implemented via developer's tools in Chrome, I noticed the following html tag for the first tab. I could expand/collapse the List of Books tab, however with no icon displayed.

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>List of Books
```

The below code is translated to above html code.

```
<p:panel header="Good Books">
    <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="null" multiple="true">
        <p:tab title="List of Books">
```

After reviewing two css files that refer to accordion class (jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css and book.css) and jquery icons documentation page, I thought following image files are maybe missing. I searched them from a project folder but I couldn't find them.

1. ui-icon-triangle-1-e.png
2. ui-icon-triangle-1-s.png

So I downloaded jquery ThemeRoller (jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.zip) by believing it should have those missing image files and I can simply import them to the project manually. The reason I chose 1.10.4 is I see jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css file from the project. However I didn't find them either from the zip file.

How can I locate those image files?

[css class related to accordion from jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css]

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
    min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
    padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-noicons {
    padding-left: .7em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-icons {
    padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
    border-top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

[css class related to accordion from book.css]

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{background:#f5f5f5;margin:0 1em;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header{border:1px solid #e4eaed;margin:0 1em;}
.accordion_icon_default {background-image:url('/images/book/accordion_right.png');width:14px;height:18px;background-position: 0 2px;}
.accordion_icon_active {background-image:url('/images/book/accordion_down.png');width:14px;height:18px;background-position: 0 2px;}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon {
    display: block; 
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default a {
    padding: 8px 25px;
} 
.accordionHeader {
    width: 760px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content.ui-widget-content {
    padding: 0px 2px !important;
 }
```

Comment: The icons are in the Primefaces jar file under META-INF.resources.primefaces-<theme>.images. Don't know if you can use that

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: Thanks! I also see accordion.css and js files under MEAT-INF. I think those image files contain all the icons in one place with different scale/size. I wonder how primefaces extract individual icon and associate it with whatever widget it goes with...

Comment: The styleclasses are hardcoded in the components themselves. How the mapping to the big image happens I have no idea..